# Bucket password in Couchbase

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase

I am creating a demo project for reative programming with springboot and Couchbase.
I have set the below properties in application.properties file:

```
spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts=localhost
spring.couchbase.bucket.name=vanquish
spring.couchbase.bucket.password=
spring.data.couchbase.repositories.type=auto
```

As I don't have any bucket level password while creating it. Still, service is not able to start because of below exception:

```
Caused by: com.couchbase.client.java.error.InvalidPasswordException: Passwords for bucket "vanquish" do not match.
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster$OpenBucketErrorHandler.call(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:651) ~[java-client-2.5.9.jar:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster$OpenBucketErrorHandler.call(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:634) ~[java-client-2.5.9.jar:na]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeMap.java:88) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onError(Subscribers.java:230) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:273) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
```

I tried searching all properties but not able to find any relevant property to set username and password or setting the password in couchbase for the bucket.

Comment: how u get user name vanquish?

Comment: this is thr bucket name not username

Comment: Which couchBase version are you using?

Comment: @deadprogrammer Provide the Administrator password that you use to login to the couchbase console on `spring.couchbase.bucket.password=`

Comment: 5.x community edition

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a couchBase version 5.x:

According to the [couchBase documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/security/security-bucket-protection.html):

> To access cluster-resources, Couchbase Server users — administrators
>   and applications — must specify a username and password.

Steps to follow:

1. Open your couchBase admin console: `http://<couchBase-host>:8091/ui/index.html#!/overview`
2. Click on 'Security'
3. click on 'Add user'

In the 'Add user' form add these parameters:

**User Name:** This ***must*** be the bucket name, in your case `vanquish`.

**Password:** Set the password that you want, this ***must*** be the value set in `spring.couchbase.bucket.password`.

**Roles:** Go to Roles -> Bucket Roles -> Bucket Admin and select your bucket, in your case `vanquish`.

Click on 'Save'.

After doing this and set the password in `spring.couchbase.bucket.password` it should work.

Comment: Glad to help. @Ertuğrul