# com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.AuthenticationException: Authentication failure on Select Bucket command

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase

I am having the below issue with *CouchbaseVersion 5.5.1*.

```
2018-11-01 12:36:51.452  WARN [promotion-customercriteria-ms,,,] [,] 1
--- [cb-io-1-2] c.c.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint        : [][KeyValueEndpoint]: Authentication Failure. 2018-11-01 12:36:51.516  WARN [promotion-customercriteria-ms,,,] [,] 1 --- [cb-io-1-2] c.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler   : Received Error during Reconfiguration.

com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.AuthenticationException: Authentication failure on Select Bucket command  at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.KeyValueSelectBucketHandler.channelRead0(KeyValueSelectBucketHandler.java:151)     at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.KeyValueSelectBucketHandler.channelRead0(KeyValueSelectBucketHandler.java:41)  at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105 2018-11-01 12:36:51.540  WARN [promotion-customercriteria-ms,,,] [,] 1
--- [localhost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [cb-computations-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: WARN [promotion-customercriteria-ms,,,] [,] 1 --- [cb-io-1-5] c.c.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint        : [][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 32 MILLISECONDS: com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.AuthenticationException: Authentication failure on Select Bucket command
  WARN [promotion-customercriteria-ms,,,] [,] 1 --- [cb-io-1-6] c.c.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint        : [][KeyValueEndpoint]: Authentication Failure.
  WARN [promotion-customercriteria-ms,,,] [,] 1 --- [cb-io-1-6] c.c.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint        : [][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could n

Comment: May [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496589/bucket-password-in-couchbase/51500324#51500324) helps you?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it could help others.
If you are using in the list of nodes other than data nodes, you should consider removing them from your configuration.
According to the [java driver documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/start-using-sdk.html), only the data nodes should be listed